# how to count multiple records and put the count no in new table

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I want to calculate number of records of column `vcofig` from table `vin_no` and put final count in table `new_stock` against column `vehiclecount`.

Table `vin_no` has columns `vcofig` and `chassis`; 
and table `new_stock` has columns `vcofig`(primary key) and `vehiclecount`.

There are 16 `vcofig` in `new_stock` and these 16 individuals are multiple time (total 80) available in `vcofig` of `vin_no`.

Below is the code. But error is

> ORA-01427: single-row sub-query returns more than one row.

```
UPDATE NEW_STOCK set VEHICLECOUNT = ( 
  select count(vin_NO.vcofig) total 
  from VIN_NO
  LEFT join NEW_STOCK on VIN_NO.VCOFIG = NEW_STOCK.VCOFIG
  GROUP BY vin_no.VCOFIG
) ;
```

Comment: How will it know which count to assign to which row being updated? hint: you know which column links the two tables, so the subquery can be restricted using that?

Comment: Skip the GROUP BY, a correlated sub-query is needed.

Comment: Why are you doing a `LEFT JOIN`? Don't you want an `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: inner join returns null value in sub query, left join gives correct count

Comment: if i skip the group by then sub query gives single output and same is reflecting in all rows of vehiclecount @jarlh

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE NEW_STOCK a set VEHICLECOUNT = 
    (select count(*) from VIN_NO b where b.VCOFIG = a.VCOFIG)
```

If VEHICLECOUNT can't be null, then:

```
UPDATE NEW_STOCK a set VEHICLECOUNT = 
    (select count(*) from VIN_NO b where b.VCOFIG = a.VCOFIG)
WHERE EXISTS 
    (select 'x' from VIN_NO c where c.VCOFIG = a.VCOFIG)
```

or alternatively:

```
UPDATE NEW_STOCK a set VEHICLECOUNT = 
    nvl((select count(*) from VIN_NO b where b.VCOFIG = a.VCOFIG),0)
```

Comment: alternative is returning 0 in all rows of vehiclecount

Comment: Does the column VCOFIG match in value between the two tables? Can you provide some sample rows of data from each table?

Comment: table vin_no 
chassis         vcofig 
ch283737 vc1203
ch121212 vc1201
ch165487 vc1201
ch123781 vc1202
ch121382 vc1203
ch128983 vc1202
ch122284 vc1200
ch137445 vc1203
 
table new_stock 
 
vcofig  vehiclecount(expected output) 
VC1203 3
VC1200 1
VC1201 2
VC1202 2
VC1204 0

Comment: hi chip L can you understand the data? because am not able to put tables in comment box as expected

Comment: Is new_stock empty and you want to populate it with counts from VIN_NO? If so, then an UPDATE is not what you want; rather, an INSERT.

Comment: there are some other columns in new_stock, i didnt mention as these were un-necessary

Comment: By empty, I meant are there already rows in the NEW_STOCK table that you simply want to update counts for, or do you want to insert new rows into the NEW_STOCK table with counts from VIN_NO?